# How to keep Leantween animation alive until server response is handled in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, keep-alive, leantween

I'm developing a slot game in Unity. For every spin, I send a spin request to server and get the results from server and set final position of symbols on screen. I want to keep wheels rolling till server response is handled.

Currently, It rolls in a given period and for a specified number of turn. Is there any means of achieving this?

```
 LTDescr action = LeanTween.value(gameObject, 0f, 1f, duration).setOnUpdate((float dt) =>
    {
        float curr = h * dt;
        int currTile = (int)(curr / _tileSize.y);

        float delta = curr - prev;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            CSSymbol s = _symbols[i];
            Vector3 v = s.transform.localPosition;
            v.y -= delta;

            if (v.y - min.y <= 0.01f)  // Symbols that get down of screen should be moved back to starting point
            {
                v.y = max.y + (v.y - min.y);
                CSSymbolType type = CSSymbolType.SymbolNone;
                if (i < count - 1 && currTile > lastRoll)
                {
                    // Last roll
                    type = _reelRandom.SmartRandomSymbol(); // set resulting symbol list
                }
                else
                {
                    type = _reelRandom.RandomSymbol(); // get random symbol type
                }
                s.SetType(type);
            }

            s.transform.localPosition = v; // set new symbol
        }
        prev = curr;
    }).setEaseInOutSine().setDelay((float)_column * delay);
```